# suggested alternative: ‘ctime’ in C++

Tags: c++

I was trying to put together a small program to see how the destructor was called and I noticed a strange behavior that I couldn't understand.
Why is it suggesting 'ctime' here that seems to have no context ?

```
jrangab@ubuntu:~/progs$ g++ --std=c++11 mk_shared_issue.cpp 
mk_shared_issue.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mk_shared_issue.cpp:20:20: error: ‘choice’ was not declared in this scope
  auto foo=creature(choice);
                    ^~~~~~
mk_shared_issue.cpp:20:20: note: suggested alternative: ‘ctime’
  auto foo=creature(choice);
                    ^~~~~~
                    ctime
jrangab@ubuntu:~/progs$
```

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class creature {
        private:
                int a;
        public:
                void get_a() { cout << "value of a = " << a;  }
                void set_a(int val ) { a = val; }
                creature( int choice );
                ~creature( );
};
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include "mk_shared_issue.hpp"
using namespace std;

creature::creature( int choice )
{
        std::cout << "calling constructor " << "\n";

        if (choice > 10)
                set_a(1);
        else
                set_a(0);
}

creature::~creature( ) { std::cout << "calling destructor" << "\n"; }


int main()
{
        //int choice=11;
        auto foo=creature(choice);
        foo.get_a();
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Nearer identifier (with [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or similar) for `choice` seems to be `ctime` (2 replacements, one deletion).

Comment: [Works fine here](https://godbolt.org/z/fn9G4bx48)

Comment: @NotAProgrammer - sorry, I  put the fixed code here by mistake. I will change it now to whatever that will trigger the error. You need to actually remove 
    int choice=11;

Comment: @badri If you remove a variable, how do you expect compiler to find that variable? Or is your question just about the `ctime` suggestion?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen - The question is about the strange note that I got. note: suggested alternative: ‘ctime’. But Jarod42's answer seems to be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `choice` is not declared, you have an error.

Compiler tries to help to fix the *"typo"* by finding the nearest identifier available.

and Nearest identifier (with some [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)) for `choice` seems to be (as you have using `namespace std;`, `std::`)`ctime` (2 replacements, one deletion).